# Can one say an architecture using websocket technology is based on client-server model?

Tags: websocket, client-server, constraints, theory

Can one say an architecture using websocket technology is based on client-server model?

By definition The **client–server model** is a distributed application structure that partitions tasks or workloads between the **providers** of a resource or service, called **servers**, and service **requesters**, called **clients**.

However using the websocket technology, two endpoints can both act as providers of a resource or service and also service requesters.

Say for example in a situation where the two endpoints are: **a user device** with a gps sensor and a **computer machine**, both connected in the network using **websocket**. And the **computer machine** is **sending requests** to obtain the current position of the user device (here the **user device** is acting as a **resource provider** and the **computer machine** as a **requester**). Later on the **user device** uses the websocket connection to **request** all its positions on the last 5 days to the computer machine (now the **user device** is acting as the **requester** and the **computer machine** as the **resource provider**).

If both devices can act as resource provider and requester, are they complying with the client-server model definition or not?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not breaking anything. End Points are not devices they are connections between devices. 
ie if we were asking each other questions and answering them

There would two connections between two 'devices' giving four endpoints. You to me and me to you. No conflict.

Comment: Could you provide some sources?

Comment: I'm sure I might have read it somewhere, but my knowledge is mainly doing. You can quote me if you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

TCP is [full duplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_duplex#Full-duplex) capable, and particularly WebSockets are full duplex. As @Tony Hopkinson pointed out, there is no conflict at all. This means, you can write and read at the same time.

WebSockets are [push technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), more suited for events; while usual request-response models are [pull technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology).

You can have both client-server or peer to peer architectures with push approach, but pull is the normal choice for pull architectures.

> [Peer-to-peer Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer#Architecture): A peer-to-peer network is designed
>   around the notion of equal peer nodes simultaneously functioning as
>   both "clients" and "servers" to the other nodes on the network. This
>   model of network arrangement differs from the client–server model
>   where communication is usually to and from a central server. A typical
>   example of a file transfer that uses the client-server model is the
>   File Transfer Protocol (FTP) service in which the client and server
>   programs are distinct: the clients initiate the transfer, and the
>   servers satisfy these requests.

You can also provide a mix of peer-to-peer and client-server. For example, you can do requests via WebSocket, and at the same time, the server could send updates on its own initiative. I don't understand what you mean with "breaking the model". WebSocket is just a communication channel. In your app both models can coexists and use the same communication channel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is not how or why is it possible that comunication using websocket in a TCP works in both directions. My Question is about the **definition** of the client-server model and its **constraints**. 

In an arquitecture where two devices both act as a **requester** and **resource provider**, can it still be based on a client-server model or not?

Comment: An architecture where both request and provide is a peer to peer architecture, not a client-server archtecture. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer#Architecture.

Comment: The question was a bit confusing, so I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: I updated my answer, but still don't get what you mean with "breaking". Cheers.

Comment: So in the example I gave in my question to describe an implementation of websocket, could you say it would be implementing the P2P model?

Comment: With "breaking" I meant "not complying with", I'll edit that too :p

Comment: @MarcioOliveira Peer to peer can be done with one bi-directional connection or two uni-directional connections. The latter would be client server (usually). Thats an implementation decision though, both ends can listen and request and in a good architecture wouldn't give a stuff how many 'wires' are required.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson But the two uni-directional connections would go against the client-server model definition no? (If you see the sistem as a hole, and not one connection at a time). Btw, I'm worried here with the theory now, not the implementation or the techonlogy, I just used it as an example.

Comment: HTTP 2.0 uses a single connection for all the requests, and they can be multiplexed. This means that the browser may issue dozens or hundreds of request at the same time, and make more requests at the same time is receiving responses, also the server can send responses in any order and even change the response order if it sees fit. It is still a client-server architecture. HTTP 1.x has the concept of persistent connection, but still waits for the response before do another request, because it is unable of correlate different requests and responses.

Comment: @vtortola The reason why HTTP maintains the client-server model is because there is only one point that requests resources (client) and only one point that serves those resources as a response (server) even thought those resources travel on the same connection and may arrive unordered to the destination.

Comment: @MarcioOliveira. No they wouldn't go against the model, the system as a whole, would have two servers and two clients, The fact that each machine has a server and a client, matters no more than one having two servers on it, or all four being one machine. If you are looking at the system as a whole, then the fact that parts of it are connected using a client server architecture should be irrelevant to it.

Comment: As I said previously, you can have both models coexisting in the same architecture. Nothing is broken, or gone against to.

Comment: @vtortola And, can they still coexist when you only have two components on the arquitecture?

Comment: @MarcioOliveira actually in HTTP 2.0 the server can propose you resources without the browser request such proposals, so in that use case the server is pushing data on its own initiative. What do you mean with "you only have two components on the arquitecture"?

Comment: @vtortola An individual [software component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_component#Software_component) is a software package, a web service, a web resource, or a module that encapsulates a set of related functions (or data). So in the example I gave there are two components (the user device and the computer machine).

Comment: @vtortola As for the HTTP example you gave, if the server push is used for only sending resources and not asking for them (even by its own initiative) then it would still be complying with the client-server definition. For example, a client asks for an image to the server and then the image gets updated, the server can issue a push to the client to send the new image. Which is different if the server "out of the blue" wants a resource from the client, say, a gps coordinate.

Comment: You can still use the push tecnology to ask for the GPS coordinate of course, but although it's possible, that doesn't seem comply with the definition of client-server, because both can be requesters.

Comment: No, it does not work like that. The browser requires an HTML document via HTTP 2.0, and then the server, sends that HTML document, and may send proposals for other files as well. That is something that the server is doing on its own, and can optionally not do it, and still comply with the protocol.

Comment: I still don't understand that concern about "complying with definitions", I think you are making up a problem that does not exist.